# Accordion toggle open/close

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sorry if this has been asked numerious times but I have an accordion which works, but I need it to toggle the currently open element. As it stands it dosen't close the currently opened element.

See my [codepen](http://codepen.io/robbo/pen/fesBI)

The Javasscript:

```
function accordion() {
    var allPanels = $('.accordion > dd').hide();

    $('.accordion > dt > a').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        allPanels.slideUp(100);
        $(this).parent().next().slideDown(100);
        return false;
    });
}

accordion();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check if the tab is already open. If it is open and you click the title then slideUp. If it is not then slideDown as you already doing.

To check if an element is visible or not you can use `.is(":visible")`

You can use:

```
 if($(this).parent().next().is(":visible") ){

            $(this).parent().next().slideUp(100);
    }
    else{
            $(this).parent().next().slideDown(100);
    }
```

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/uKAvb)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
$(this).parent().next().slideToggle(100);      
allPanels.not($(this).parent().next()).slideUp(100);
```

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/HbLvh)